# How to render multiple notifications with help of notistack in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, notistack

I'm trying to use React's 'notistack' module to display several notifications as a stack. However, it appears that I am making a mistake, as Whenever I receive a warning:

`react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render)`

I'm using the state here to set the Response messages(they are coming from api), which are an array of notifications. Once the alerts have been rendered, I should also make the state of the Response messages an empty array.

renderPage.js

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";

import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

import Notification from "../../components/Notification";
import { handleResponse } from "../../services/responseHandler";
import { SelectedRunnerContext } from "./RunnersPage";

export function RunnersForm() {
    const { selected } = useContext(SelectedRunnerContext);
    const [responseMessages, setResponseMessages] = useState([]);
    const notistackRef = React.createRef();
    const onClickDismiss = (key) => () => {
        notistackRef.current.closeSnackbar(key);
    };

    const MakePostRequest = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setResponseMessages([]);
        const data = {
            selected_runners: selected,
        };

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: data,
        };
        axios
            .post("/messages", requestOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                const result = handleResponse(response.data);
                setResponseMessages(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={MakePostRequest}>Post</Button>
            {!!responseMessages.length && (
                <SnackbarProvider
                    maxSnack={4}
                    ref={notistackRef}
                    dense
                    preventDuplicate
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "right",
                    }}
                    TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                    sx={{
                        width: 700,
                    }}
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: 700,
                    }}
                    action={(key) => (
                        <Button onClick={onClickDismiss(key)}>
                            <Typography
                                variant="subtitle2"
                                style={{
                                    fontWeight: 600,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: "#00579b",
                                }}
                            >
                                Dismiss
                            </Typography>
                        </Button>
                    )}
                >
                    <Notification messages={responseMessages} />
                </SnackbarProvider>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Notification.js

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

export default function Notification(props) {
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
    const { messages } = props;
    const options = {
        variant: "success",
        autoHideDuration: 6000,
        transitionDuration: { enter: 400, exit: 400 },
    };

    messages.forEach((msg) => {
        enqueueSnackbar(msg, options);
    });
    return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by wrapping up the App with the Notification provider:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

function MakeGlobal() {
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
    window.enqueueSnackbar = enqueueSnackbar;
    return null;
}

export function displayNotification(messages) {
    const options = {
        variant: "success",
        autoHideDuration: 6000,
        transitionDuration: { enter: 400, exit: 400 },
    };

    messages.forEach((msg) => {
        window.enqueueSnackbar(msg, options);
    });
}

export function Provider({ children }) {
    const notistackRef = React.createRef();
    const onClickDismiss = (key) => () => {
        notistackRef.current.closeSnackbar(key);
    };
    return (
        <SnackbarProvider
            maxSnack={4}
            ref={notistackRef}
            dense
            preventDuplicate
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "right",
            }}
            sx={{
                width: 700,
            }}
            style={{
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: 700,
            }}
            action={(key) => (
                <Button onClick={onClickDismiss(key)}>
                    <Typography
                        variant="subtitle2"
                        style={{
                            fontWeight: 600,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: "#00579b",
                        }}
                    >
                        Dismiss
                    </Typography>
                </Button>
            )}
        >
            <MakeGlobal />
            {children}
        </SnackbarProvider>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <snackbar.Provider>
                <AppRoutes />
                <CssBaseline />
            </snackbar.Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
         
    );
```